# flutter_svg -> how to compose an image from different svg files and get a specific area of the composed image

Tags: svg, flutter

I am composing different SVGs of a body (arms, legs, head, hair, eyes, eybrows ...) to get an avatar. There are about 1.500 SVGs. The SVGs are without any text, effects, ... -> simple paths. 
Some are colored, some get a transparency.

For the composing I am currently using a Stack with about 20 SvgPictures.

The pictures of the head are aprearing in lists with hundreds of entries.

**1. question**
This approach makes sense in terms of performance

**2. question**
In some cases we have to "zoom" on the trousers, in others on the face, ...
Using the alignment we can get get to the matching excerpt - but sometimes we have to scale the image to a specific value -> how can we achive this (we need to use "fit: BoxFit.none" to avoid standard scaling and there is no option for our requirements).

Comment: how did you compose the SVGs ? I'm looking for a solution for a problem like yours where I have to compose multiple svgs into a single image

Comment: Currently I just use a Stack-Widget like layers in photoshop...